# How to get a reference when building a test set with xgboost.QuantileDMatrix

Tags: xgboost, quantile-regression

I'm using xgboost for quantile regression, and for that, I have to construct a `xgboost.QuantileDMatrix` object for training.

[Based on the documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.QuantileDMatrix), it seems that I need to keep the original `QuantileDMatrix` used for fitting the models as a reference (the `ref` parameter) when making predictions. This is extremely impractical, because my prediction environment is much lighter than the fitting environment and the memory limits become a concern with the heavy fitting data.

Is there any workaround or other solutions for this?